# Updating Android App on Android App Market

Tags: android

I want to update a Application on Android App Market but the problem is I have a two builds on with the resources for one kind of Devices that is 320x480 and sdk1.5 and another one is for 480x800 and sdk2.1 now how m'I Supposed to do this and How is it Possible. Please Give me some light over this.

Comment: I noticed that myself would tend to scare people off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ref - http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-12/msg03004.html

You can use different package name but same manifest label. Not recomended tho

Comment: There Should a Better Idea Than This... Man this really something that would be real Trouble

Comment: Android provides you with all the means to make apps that support multiple OS versions and device properties.